# How to upload mapping.txt to App Center in Jenkins

Tags: java, android, jenkins, visual-studio-app-center

Jenkins version: 2.299
App Center plugin: [0.11.1](https://plugins.jenkins.io/appcenter/)

I want to automatically upload the `mapping.txt` file after uploading the apk to app center but I didn't see any option for that, how can I achieve this?

***Jenkins Options:***
[image]

***App Center:***
[image]